# Avoid flash in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash, webbrowser-control

I have an c# .net2 project with a web browser control in winforms.
I want it to load a page - so far so good - and make it avoid flash content.
How can I make the webbrowser not using flash plugin?
The goal is to call e.g. sites which have an alternative to it.
Lets take youtube. If my browser doesn't support flash it uses the html5 video tag.
That behavior I want my webbrowser control to prefer.

Any ideas how I should start?

Comment: clear so far what i am driving at?

Comment: Can anybody explain the techniques being used by youtube to decide whether they use flash or html5?

Comment: have you found any solution for disabling flash in webbrowser control ?